# Trouble Establishing Ouath2 Connection to Microsoft Dynamics via Rails Oauth2 gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth-2.0, microsoft-dynamics

I am new to authentication using Oauth2, and was hoping someone could provide some guidance on how to use the oauth2 gem to correctly perform authentication so as to get a token with Microsoft Dynamics.

I have been able to authorize and get a token with Postman, but as these types of applications greatly facilitate the overall process, it can be difficult to map these things to code, especially when the concepts are new.

For the access token, I have at my disposal:

- The Auth URL, which is of the form "https://login.windows.net/<CUSTOMER_IDENTIFIER_HASH>/authorize?resource=https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com
- The Access Token URL, which is of the form "https://login.windows.net/<CUSTOMER_IDENTIFIER_HASH>/oauth2/token?resource=https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com"
- The client_id
- The client_secret

I've tried the various examples online, but I either get a nondescript error from oauth2 such as:

OAuth2::Error ():

Or, in other cases, something more particular:

OAuth2::Error ({"code"=>"RequestDataInvalid", "message"=>"Request data is invalid."}:
{"error": {"code": "RequestDataInvalid","message": "Request data is invalid."}}):

Does anyone have any real, working examples on how to successfully obtain a token?

Answer (score 0):

Finaly cracked it.

Had to respecitvely move the resource element out of the auth and the access token urls to:

```
https://login.windows.net/<CUSTOMER_IDENTIFIER_HASH>/authorize
https://login.windows.net/<CUSTOMER_IDENTIFIER_HASH>/oauth2/token
```

At that point, i set the client as:

```
client = OAuth2::Client.new(
      client_id,
      client_secret,
      site: base_url,
      grant_type: "client_credentials",
      resource: "https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com",
      authorize_url: auth_url,
      token_url: token_url,
    )
```

Above, the base_url is:

```
https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/v2.0/<CUSTOMER_IDENTIFIER_HASH>
```

Then, i call the client to get an auth_code and had to explicitly pass the resource parameter:

```
client.auth_code.authorize_url(:redirect_uri => 'http://localhost:8080/oauth2/callback', resource: "https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com")
```

I'm not sure if the resource is necessary when getting the token, but finally, I obtain it as follows:

```
token = client.password.get_token(<AUTHENTICATION_LOGIN>, <AUTHENTICATION_PASS>, resource: "https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com")
```

then i can use the token to perform get commands:

```
token.get('https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/v2.0/Sandbox/api/v2.0/companies(<COMPANY_ID_HASH>)/customers', :headers => { 'Accept' => 'application/json' })
```

I have a feeling I have to do some cleanup on the url for the final get command, but it seems to work this way.